# Loading Model Array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a model array that I use in my WebApi Get method. After I load my model array `Prem.Model.P_2.InsuredContacts[] Ins` I would like to add an additional  empty row to it after loading it. How can I do it?

```
Prem.Model.P_2.InsuredContacts[] Ins = new Prem.BLL.P_2.InsuredContacts().LoadArr(insId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of an array after it's initialized, so you need to create a new one. Plenty of ways to do this, but I'd do something like:

```
var InsList = new Prem.BLL.P_2.InsuredContacts()
    .LoadArr(insId).ToList();
InsList.Add(new Prem.BLL.P_2.InsuredContacts());
var Ins = InsList.ToArray();
```